# .net winform project structure in subversion

Tags: .net, svn, projects-and-solutions, directory-structure, ankhsvn

I am about to start on a .net winform project. I am confused on how to setup project structure in SVN. Apart from main GUI, I will write few common libs like communication layer etc. these libs will be used in this project and also will be used in other projects as well, so I don't want to put these libs under gui project.

How do people generally create project structure in svn for these type of projects.

Should I first create project structure in svn using some tool (tortoise etc..) ?
if Yes then how do you create VS projects in VS so that project files etc go in correct folders

if I first create structure in VS 2010. How do I commit them accordingly in svn so that project directory structure is maintained? I am using AnkhSVN in VS but not able to do this, every time I try the dir structure in SVN is different from what i want.

How/where to add solution files and solution folders?

apologies if these questions are very basic or vague but in eclipse I never found it difficult to setup a new project. I use maven standard dir structure and everthing seems to be so obvious that I never faced this kind of issue in java world.

To summarise, if someone can give me steps to create a very simple MVC project structure in VS/SVN

GUI(main project)
 
--Model
 
--View
 
--Utils

CommLayer (this is one of common libs which will be used in this project as well as others later).

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Guidance Packages may be the way to go here

See 
[Creating Guidance Packages](http://jelle.druyts.net/2006/06/26/GAS02CreatingAGuidancePackage.aspx)

If I can offer one word of advice - with your common libs that are used across projects I would encourage you to have releases of these so the libs may be common but projects can use different releases of these.

To facilitate this have an ExternallReferences folder which have the released DLL's for you common libs in and reference them in your project